# A group acting acylindrically on a fine hyperbolic graph with infinite edge stabilizers

Tags: gr.group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

I am looking for an example of a group $G$ that acts (cocompactly and) acylindrically on a hyperbolic graph $\Gamma$, such that
a) the graph $\Gamma$ is fine,
b) $\Gamma$ is not a tree,
c) not all edges have finite stabilizer,
d) the action of $G$ on $\Gamma$ is minimal, i.e. there is no proper, connected $G$-invariant subgraph of $\Gamma$.

Here I use the definition that $G$ acts acylindrical on $\Gamma$ iff there is a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that all geodesic segments of length $k$ in $\Gamma$ have finite (pointwise) stabilizer.

Examples are known if one condition is dropped: If I drop c), then any relative hyperbolic group (in the sense of Bowditch) is an example. If I drop b) it is easy enough to construct examples by taking say a malnormal subgroup $C\leq A$ and letting $A\ast_C B$ act on its Bass-Serre tree. If I drop a), then any acylindrically hyperbolic group will do by definition (at least if I drop cocompactly as well).

Does anyone know where to find an example in the literature satisfying a)-d) and/or how to construct one?

Edit (Oct 23rd 2015): Condition d) was added.
Edit (Oct 24th 2015): added "connected" in Condition d)

Comment: Could you define what a fine graph is?

Comment: One could easily concoct artificial examples from known examples. For instance, take a relatively hyperbolic example, so c) fails, let $V$ be a vertex with infinite stabilizer, and for each vertex in the orbit $G \cdot V$, attach an edge with both endpoints at that vertex.

Comment: "Fine" is defined by Bowditch, meaning that for each edge $E$ and integer $L \ge 1$ the graph has only finitely many circuits of length $L$ passing through $E$. http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgak/papers/bhb-relhyp.pdf

Comment: @LeeMosher thanks for the example! When asking the question I had a minimal action of $G$ on $\Gamma$ in mind though. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @SvenjaKnopf: You should add "connected" subgraph to your condition (d), otherwise, you can, say, omit all the edges. But even this is not enough: You can start with a group action on a tree and replace an edge $e$ (with infinite stabilizer $G_e$) with infinitely many edges (connecting the same pair of vertices) and let $G_e$ permute these new edges transitively (but maybe not simply transitively).

Comment: @Misha Replacing one edge in a tree with infinitely many edges between its two endpoints results in a graph that is not fine. So this is excluded by a).

Comment: What about the following construction: Let $G \curvearrowright T$ be an action on a tree satisfying the conditions a), c) and d). Now, $G \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ acts on (the 1-squeleton of) $T \times [0,1]$, where $\mathbb{Z}_2$ permutes the two copies $T \times \{ 0 \}$ and $T \times \{ 1 \}$ of $T$.

Comment: @Seirios If $T$ has a vertex $v$ of infinite valency (which it has to have to satisfy c) and d)), then the 1-skeleton of $T\times [0,1]$ is not a fine graph: the edge between $(v,0)$ and $(v,1)$ is contained in any of the infinitely many circuits of length 4 starting at $(v,0)$ running through $(w,0), (w,1), (v,1)$ back to $(v,0)$ where $w$ is any vertex in $T$ adjacent to $v$.

Comment: @SvenjaKnopf, it's easy to modify Lee's example to satisfy condition (d).  For instance, if the infinite vertex stabilizer $G_V$ has a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ quotient, then Lee's extra loop can be replaced by a pair of loops, swapped by $\mathbb{Z}/2$.